# Jupyter Notebook: How to re-run notebook with different parameters (e.g. input data file)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a notebook, which can do some complex data analysis with **one dataset**. At the end, it saves the notebook and converts into `HTML`, so I can view the result later without running the notebook again. One example is this:

https://cdn.rawgit.com/cqcn1991/Wind-Speed-Analysis/master/output_HTML/marham.html

Now, I want to run the notebook over **many, different datasets**. How can I do it?

Maybe something like

```
files = [
'./data/NCDC/cn/binhai/dat.txt', 
'./data/NCDC/cn/luogang/dat.txt',
"./data/NCDC/cn/tianjing/dat.txt", 
"./data/NCDC/cn/gushi/dat.txt", 
"./data/NCDC/cn/yueyang/dat.txt", 
]
for input_file_path in files:
    run_notebook('GMM.ipynb', input_file_path)
```

---

My thougths:

1. I find [Run parts of a ipython notebook in a loop / with different input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635341/run-parts-of-a-ipython-notebook-in-a-loop-with-different-input-parameter), but it's run part of the cells within the notebook.
2. [Scientific Computing & Ipython Notebook: How to organize code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427747/scientific-computing-ipython-notebook-how-to-organize-code/38192558#38192558) provides a solution to run notebook within a host notebook. However, it's not that the target notebook gets runned, but the target notebook's code run within the host's environment. That leaves the original notebook un-changed, and when saving into HTML, the results are all the same.

Comment: [nbparameterise](https://github.com/takluyver/nbparameterise) is one take on this.

Comment: @ThomasK this is very creative. Why didn't see it be used by others?

Comment: Thanks! I haven't promoted it very much, it's got a really awkward name, and it's kind of hard to explain quickly what it is. ;-)

Comment: @ThomasK I'd say currently the SciPy community lacks a way to promote additive and productive works. Yours is an example, and so is my involvement in [toc2](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/toc2).

Comment: @ThomasK I think a framework like `Ruby on Rails` would be helpful to promote these best practices and also keep the original Scipy/Jupyter Notebook code repo lean.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. We have many web frameworks; Django is most often likened to Ruby on Rails, while Jupyter uses Tornado. Do you mean we should build a website to help people discover useful tools?